# Every time 3d game kit project start it gives 14 errors

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

Every time I open unity project it gives me errors and as I am very new to game development, I don't understand what these errors I tried to google it and find everywhere but I didn't get any solutions.
These errors are like:

1. ReleaseAllScriptsCaches
2. Null Reference Exception
3. The type or namespace name "Cinemachine" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
4. The type or namespace name 'PostProcessing' does not exist in the namespace 'UnityEngine.Rendering' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

and many more.

Here is the reference image of errors.

[image]

Comment: Do you have the [Cinemachine package](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.cinemachine@2.8/manual/index.html) installed in your project via the PackageManager ?

Comment: Looks like the version of Cinemachine you've got (and possibly 3dGameKit) may be incompatible with your version of Unity. Go to the package manager, remove Cinemachine and 3dGameKit and re-install them.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing Cinemachine and PostProcessing. go to window->Package Manager and install these packages and the errors should go away.